# Change font in next.js (app router) on the server side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to create a process for creating digital certificates.

The user fills 2 fields in the form: his name and age, then on the server side, I load a demo certificate and I want to place the user's name and age in specific places.

Everything works great, except for one thing - I need the fonts to be different for the name and age (later I want to add signatures too, so I'll need a different font).

When I try to load a font from a local folder in the project, the font simply does not load, I get the certificate with the default font, in addition, there are no errors in the console from the server or the browser, I tried many ways (loading a font via HTTPS, different types of font files such as TTF, OTF, WOFF2 ), in all cases I get the same result.

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { createCanvas, loadImage, registerFont, Canvas } from 'canvas';


const fontPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'src', 'fonts', 'fredoka', 'Fredoka-Regular.ttf');

export async function POST(request: Request, response: Response) {
  const { name, age} = await request.json()

  registerFont(fontPath, { family: 'Fredoka' });

  const image = await loadImage('https://www.myImage/demo.png');

  // Create a canvas and draw the image
  const canvas = createCanvas(image.width, image.height);
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

  // Add the name to the canvas
  context.font = `120px Fredoka`;
  context.textAlign = 'center';
  context.fillStyle = 'black';
  context.fillText(name, 1000, 880);

  context.font = '40px Verdana'; // Change font and size
  context.fillStyle = 'black'; // Change color
  context.fillText(age, 670, 1675);

  // Convert the modified canvas to a buffer
  const buffer = canvas.toBuffer();

  const outputPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'public', 'images', `${name}.png`);
  fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, buffer);


  return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "image created" }));
};
```

I tried next js documentation, youtube, chatGPT, and google search.

I looking for a solution for this way or another way.